# The Answer Box doesn't accept XML code

Tags: discussion, bug, markdown

When I'm trying to enter an XML snippet into the answer box, it is not showing; I think because of its similarity to HTML. Though I don't know if this is a deliberate attempt or a bug in the system.

like this

** - This is a piece of XML code inserted in the area just above this edit

```
<httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled" />
```

** - This is what I originally also tried in the Stack Overflow answer box but I couldn't achieve this. [Here is a link to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621836/why-is-mvc-page-compilation-forcing-constant-app-restarts-on-my-azure-web-app/43305746?noredirect=1#comment73676324_43305746)

Comment: it is not a duplicate

Comment: @ParvSharma Yes it is. Read the section titled "Code within a numbered or bulleted list"

Answer (score 3):

```
<httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled" />
```

Use the <kbd>{}</kbd> button. or use 4 spaces before the code.It is markdown syntax.

Update:
if your code is part of a numbering/bullet points, your indentation of 4 spaces should start *after* the numbering indentation.
Updated the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305746/4826457) link.

Comment: i tried doing that. but cudnt achieve the results that i could here.

Comment: @ParvSharma You need an extra 4 spaces if the code part is part of a list block.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer

Comment: http://www.markdowntutorial.com/ try this